# How to do calculations with database values in Classic ASP?

Tags: sql, asp-classic, user-defined-types, type-mismatch

I have to do a calculation to an integer value in classic asp, but i keep getting "type mismatch" error on this line: X = tempID + 1

this is my code:

```
 Set TheRS = Conn.Execute("select top 1 xx from W_TABLE order by IDX desc")
   tempID = TheRS("xx")
   X = tempID + 1
   TheRS.Close
   Set TheRS = nothing
```

tempX is of type "User-defined Type"... i'm assuming that's why it wont let me add 1 to it... how can i make this happen?

Comment: shouldn't it be `X = tempID + 1`?

Comment: Please pay more attention to your tag choices, specifically the big "DO NOT USE" message on the pop up help text for the `asp` tag.

Comment: what they said + you could add if not TheRS.eof then ... end if around tempID = TheRS("xx") to make sure your recordset got results

Comment: @KlausByskovHoffmann - sorry that was a typo on my part, that's how i have it now.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn what do you mean? what pop up help text?

Comment: @xrum, mouse over one of the tags for a minute, and you'll see. The same messages pop up more quickly as you are typing the tags in to the question.

Comment: Also of note .. you closed your recordset when it was done and even destroy the object .. but what about the connection too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it working by changing the select.

```
select top 1 xx+1 from W_TABLE order by IDX desc
```

thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem with numeric/decimal columns.  ADO returns the value as a Decimal type, but VBScript doesn't really support the Decimal type.  About the only thing you can do with a variable that contains a Decimal type value is convert it using `CInt`, `CDbl`, or any of the other conversion functions.  My guess is that if you were to inspect the value of `VarType(tempID)`, you would see `14`, which corresponds to [`vbDecimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/10wcf65z%28VS.85%29.aspx).

To work around this, you should convert the value using `CDbl` (or `CInt` if you don't care about the decimal portion).

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if the recordset is end of file first. (`If TheRS.Eof Then`)
2. It seems to me "xx", whatever that is, isn't actually an integer. Are you sure your query is returning a numerical answer?
3. Chances are that's why you can't add 1 to it. Try cast it as an integer first: `X = CInt(tempID) + 1`
4. Response.Write(tempID) before adding 1 and see what value it has

Not to be rude but that code is indecipherable! W_TABLE? IDX? xx? These are all terrible variable and schema names. I sincerely hope that you have just sanitized your real, appropriately named variables for more abstract, confusing ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to bother what your database query returns this should do the trick:

```
X = CInt("0" & tempID) + 1
```

Comment: Concatenating a "0" doesn't affect the conversion to a numerical value.

Comment: Sure it doesn't affect the conversion - but as is explictly said: If he doesn't care if anything is returned by his db query +1 will still work. This is not a solution on how to properly handle db query results but a simple trick and I don't see why my answer deserves a downvote.